# Query to retrieve data where a variable is stored in the column name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that looks like this.

```
width | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40
----------------------------
  10  | $2 | $3 | $4 | $5
  20  | $3 | $4 | $5 | $6
  30  | $4 | $5 | $6 | $7
  40  | $5 | $6 | $7 | $8
```

The top row are column names. How would I pull a money value out if i were given the two numerical values?

Or what is the easiest way to reorganise this data into new columns?

EDIT:

The numbers in the column name are heights and the numbers in the width column are widths.

If I were to plug in the numbers 10 for height and 20 for width, I'd want $3 to be my result.

Thank you!

Comment: can you give an example on what result you want to have?

Comment: The question is very ambiguous.  What is this data? What are these "numbers" that you are getting? Give an example of your input and expected corresponding output. What code are you executing and what errors are you getting?

Comment: Assuming we are talking about width/length... SELECT \`20\` WHERE width='10'? A better way would be to have the structure as "width","length","price" and do SELECT price WHERE width='20' and length='10'

Comment: It seems like one of your values will be column (right after the SELECT) and the other a row (WHERE clause). What are your worries all about? SELECT ``10`` FROM ``myTable`` WHERE ``width`` = '20'; (omg comment styles... use backquote to surround 10 -> `)

Comment: @GarethL `SELECT 20` will always return number `20`.  If _20_ is the column name, you'll need `SELECT ``20`` FROM ``table``...`. Those should be single back-quotes around _20_ and table name, but I can't figure out how to show those.

Comment: Just throwin this out there.. if this data is static and not going be changed.. you could just cut out the database completely and use the equation `(width_value + column_value)/10` ..

Comment: @AleksG - yes, I was working on a laptop with an Italian keyboard (no backtick symbol) and couldn't remember the ALT+#### sequence. I've edited now. (It's ALT+0096, btw)

Comment: @GarethL If i could offer you a beer i would! i've (lazily) searched that code for ages `I'm so happy now`... damn the italian keyboard layout

Comment: @STTLCU - glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
// assert $height column exists before the query
$sql = "select {$height}
        from table
        where width = :b_width";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN @height=10 THEN height10
       WHEN @height=20 THEN height20
       WHEN @height=30 THEN height30
       WHEN @height=40 THEN height40
   END value
FROM yourtable
WHERE
  width=@width
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b16b0/1).

Answer (score 0):

the best way would be to refactor your database, with a normalized design.

table_1 : heights, contains a single column with the heights you have

table_2 : widths, contains a single column with the widths you have

table_3 : h_w_values, contains 3 columns: 1.height, 2.width, 3.value of the pair

This is normalized, easy to extend for N heights and M widths.
Optional: consider a table_4 for the possible values (lets say you have fixed tariffs for your packages, or whatever) and change table_3 to (height, width, tariff_id)